# Upload data to database with JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax

How can I upload data to database with AJAX, JSON and PHP?
Here is the code.

**AJAX**

```
    function saveToTheDB(ratedIndex) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'fetch.php',
            method: 'POST',
            cache: 'false',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                ratedIndex: ratedIndex
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
```

**PHP**

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    require_once 'includes\dbh.inc.php';
    $rate = $_POST['ratedIndex'];
    if(isset($_GET['userid'])){
    if($db->query(" INSERT INTO `recipes_ratings` (`recipe_rating_id`, `recipe_id`, `user_id`, `rating`)
    VALUES (null, 3 , 8, '".$rate."')
    "))   
    }
    echo json_encode($rate);
}
```

What have I done wrong?
Can some one help me to solve this problem? Thank you very much!

**EDIT**

ERROR
[I get back a full object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eq5D5.jpg)

Comment: If you present more specific error details would be good.

Comment: Sorry, I added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the response points you have syntax error, here I refactored your code in order to work.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    require_once 'includes\dbh.inc.php';
    $rate = $_POST['ratedIndex'];

    if (isset($_GET['userid'])) {
        if($db->query("INSERT INTO `recipes_ratings` (`recipe_rating_id`, `recipe_id`, `user_id`, `rating`) VALUES (null, 3 , 8, '".$rate."')")) {
            // implementation if query is successful
        } 
    }

    echo json_encode($rate);
}
```

**JFYI**: Avoid directly placing the input variables into the query, you should use [**Prepared Statements**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: I tried. Same...

Comment: i've edited my answer, check it now.

Comment: Thanks! It work (uploads to the database), but again, I get an object in console because I add a new line: $recipeid = $_GET['recipe_id'];